# Some of the links in Wordpress when moved from localhost to host are broken

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I moved my Wordpress website from localhost to the host. I changed the URL in 
wp-option and changed the URL in the panel settings also based of this tutorial: 
https://blog.templatetoaster.com/move-wordpress-localhost-to-live-server/
I used this command  `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'localhost/test/', 'www.mylivesite.com/');` on wp_posts and wp_options and wp_links
which changed some rows.Most of the URLs works fine but some links are broken and a part of my css not loading. 
appreciate any help

Comment: can you try `settings > permalinks` don't edit anything just save

Comment: Go to setting->permalinks and save also try install better search replace plugin then just replace the localhost urls with live

Comment: Try to restart the webserver (service apache|nginx restart) and drop your local cache of your website (Control + F5). And check if there are still any localhost links in the database. You can check this easily by exporting the database and searching through the file. If you found any, try to change them through wordpress. If this isn't possible you can also do this through the database. If there are too many issues, you can also fix the links in the exported file, backup the db, and reimport the exported and fixed file.

Comment: check the path of the broken link by inspecting or clicking on it. what link it is generating and what should be the right link you want... also, check the path of css generating on live site and what is the difference from local site... check from which table those links are generating and solve your problem

Comment: saving permalinks didn't help. also I used better search replace and It didn't fix it either.

Comment: If its not too late, I'd *highly* recommend starting again - it can be very difficult to fully recover a broken site. It'd be much safer, simpler & quicker to remove the messed up copy from the host and use the [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) or something similar instead. I've used Duplicator for years and I wouldn't dream of migrating a site without it - it literally does all the hard work for you. It creates a zip with everything that you copy across, and then run a simple 4-step extraction and you're done!

Comment: I used a theme that installed with duplicator. I don't have a time to start from zero. I uploaded the website and right now I'm updating every broken items

Comment: but some of my widgets are gone mostly in footer section

Comment: It will take you *30 minutes* to start again with a brand new copy using Duplicator... you've lost *days* trying to fix the broken items.

Comment: I used the duplicator but the permalink has a problem. when it's on simple mode I can't edit site and when it's not on simple mode I can edit site but the links to my pages are broken.